# How do I create a folder In Bluemix for Java Web Application?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, ibm-cloud, hibernate-search, object-storage

I have a Spring MVC application with hibernate MySQL. I have the following code for hibernate Search configuration:

```
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.default.directory_provide", "filesystem");

jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "C:\\Index");
```

1. I need to specify a folder so that Hibernate search can have index
   base in a filesystem. How can I achieve this in Bluemix?
2. Is there a way I can achieve this using Object Storage Service in
   Bluemix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is technically possible to do number 1 (you can for example save the index under /tmp directory), it is not recommended.

Since Bluemix is Cloud Application the local filesystem is ephemeral will be recreated every time you restart or restage your application, so you will not be able to persist that file.

You can use Object Storage to store the file and good tutorial is available here:
https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connecting-to-ibm-object-storage-for-bluemix-with-java/

Comment: But how do I set hibernate jpa property to store in object storage? If any sample code would be helpful

Comment: I don't have any sample code available, but I believe you need to set your jpa property to user infinispan as the directory_provider. Another option is to deploy your application using IBM Containers (i.e you would have to dockerize your app) and then you can persist the index in volumes.